# React Invalid Host Header Error when deploying to azure app service

Tags: reactjs, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

i having a problem when i want to deploy my react application to my personal azure app service 
and the error i am getting is Invalid Host Error.
when i check the log after deployment i see that the app is running normally and everything should be ok but when i open the browser i have that error.
and I'm using visual studio code azure tool extension for the deployment.

i am not modifying anything in webpack because i am using react-script and i don't want to because i still no nothing about how to work with webpacks

i tried add the .env file with HOST=myserver.com
but it didn't work and by myserver.com i mean the url i am getting from azure to browse my web site, i mean the one with .azurewebsite.net

i have done some research about this issue but almost all the solutions i found involve editing the webpack configurations,

so is there anyway for me to fix this issue?